# Binding view with model (view doesn't update)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

i'm implementing something, that if i select something in my listbox, some textboxes come visible. So i can fill in some details of the selected item. I already implemented a visibilityconverter and this is my code of xaml and viewmodel:

The items in the listbox are objects of class Question

```
public Question SelectedQuestionDropList
        {
            get { return selectedQuestionDrop; }
            set
            {
            selectedQuestionDrop = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedQuestionDropList");

            Visible = true;

            }
        }
```

this is my property of Visibility:

```
public Boolean Visible
        {
            get { return visible; }
            set { visible = value; }
        }
```

my xaml looks like this:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedQuestionDropList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" 
 DisplayMemberPath="Description"
  />

 <TextBox Height="23" Visibility="{Binding Path=Visible, Converter={StaticResource boolToVis},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode}"  />
```

But i have a problem, when i select something, the property visible is set to true, but the visibility of the textbox stays false .. so my view doesn't update with the viewmodel. 
someone who knows what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the Visibility Binding to update you have to change your property to call OnPropertyChanged:

```
    public Boolean Visible
    {
        get { return visible; }
        set 
        { 
           visible = value; 
           OnPropertyChanged("Visible");
        }
    }
```